# awk 3 consecutive empty lines as the match pattern

Tags: awk, match

I need to use 3 consecutive empty lines as the match pattern.  The following example has 3 empty lines between "rain" and "sun".

The example:

```
cat
flower


rabbit
grass
rain



sun
```

The following codes doesn't work:

```
/\n\n\n/ {print "3 consecutive empty lines found"}
```

Or

```
/^$\n^$\n^$\n/ {print "3 consecutive empty lines found"}
```

Or

```
/^$^$^$/ {print "3 consecutive empty lines found"}
```

Or

```
/'^$'\n'^$'\n'^$'\n/ {print "3 consecutive empty lines found"}
```

My bash version is 3.2

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? there might be better tools for the job.

Comment: awk reads the file by separating into lines based on the Record Separator, which is by default \n, so you won't be able to test multiple lines in one go like that.  You'll need to do some sort of rolling count of sequential empty lines. (edit: like the answer just said..)

Comment: Given you are writing an awk script, why would you tell us the bash version instead of the awk version??? The awk version is important, the bash version is a useful to this question as knowing what kind of car you drive. Anyway - the right way to do this will depend what your expected output is so please post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following could help:

```
awk '/^$/{if(++i>2){print "3 consecutive empty lines found";exit}}/./{i=0}'
```

With `/^$/` we count the number of consecutive empty lines. If we find a non empty line with `/./`, we set the counter to zero. If the counter reaches 3, we print our message and exit.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  It works for me after playing a little with it. I use this pattern match (the 3 consecutive empty lines) as one of the 3 or 4 different patterns to stop a search.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are all you need is (using GNU awk for multi-char RS):

```
BEGIN{RS="^$"} /(^|\n)\n\n\n/ {print "3 consecutive empty lines found"}
```

but without showing us the expected output that's just a guess.